MongoDB Authentication Issues with Node.js and Mongo-Express in Docker Compose setup
I was trying to use docker in a project I built a while back and I'm having trouble with MongoDB authentication when using Docker Compose. Here's my docker-compose.yml:
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "${PORT}:${PORT}"
    environment:
      - PORT=${PORT}
      - CONNECTION_STRING=${CONNECTION_STRING}
      - ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET=${ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET}
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongo
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}

The Dockerfile for building the web-app image is:
FROM node:20-alpine3.19

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5001

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]

The .env file used is:
PORT=5001

CONNECTION_STRING=mongodb://admin:adminpassword@mongo:27017/key_ring_backend_3

MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=adminpassword

The mongo runs without any problem, but the web app and mongo-express can't connect to the mongo.
The web app gives the following error:
2024-06-27 06:34:30 
2024-06-27 06:34:30 > key_ring_backend_api@1.0.0 start
2024-06-27 06:34:30 > node ./src/server.js
2024-06-27 06:34:30 
2024-06-27 06:34:30 Server running on port 5001
2024-06-27 06:34:43 Error: MongoServerError: Authentication failed.

Mongo-express gives the following error
2024-06-27 06:34:40 Welcome to mongo-express 1.0.2
2024-06-27 06:34:40 ------------------------
2024-06-27 06:34:30 /docker-entrypoint.sh: connect: Connection refused
2024-06-27 06:34:30 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Connection refused
2024-06-27 06:34:31 /docker-entrypoint.sh: connect: Connection refused
2024-06-27 06:34:31 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Connection refused
2024-06-27 06:34:32 /docker-entrypoint.sh: connect: Connection refused
2024-06-27 06:34:32 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Connection refused
2024-06-27 06:34:33 /docker-entrypoint.sh: connect: Connection refused
2024-06-27 06:34:33 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Connection refused
2024-06-27 06:34:34 /docker-entrypoint.sh: connect: Connection refused
2024-06-27 06:34:34 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Connection refused
2024-06-27 06:34:35 /docker-entrypoint.sh: connect: Connection refused
2024-06-27 06:34:35 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Connection refused
2024-06-27 06:34:36 /docker-entrypoint.sh: connect: Connection refused
2024-06-27 06:34:36 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Connection refused
2024-06-27 06:34:37 /docker-entrypoint.sh: connect: Connection refused
2024-06-27 06:34:37 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Connection refused
2024-06-27 06:34:38 /docker-entrypoint.sh: connect: Connection refused
2024-06-27 06:34:38 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Connection refused
2024-06-27 06:34:39 /docker-entrypoint.sh: connect: Connection refused
2024-06-27 06:34:39 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Connection refused
2024-06-27 06:34:43 Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://admin:****@mongo:27017/"
2024-06-27 06:34:43 /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:227
2024-06-27 06:34:43                     callback(new error_1.MongoServerError(document));
2024-06-27 06:34:43                              ^
2024-06-27 06:34:43 
2024-06-27 06:34:43 MongoServerError: Authentication failed.
2024-06-27 06:34:43     at Connection.onMessage (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:227:30)
2024-06-27 06:34:43     at MessageStream.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:60:60)
2024-06-27 06:34:43     at MessageStream.emit (node:events:517:28)
2024-06-27 06:34:43     at processIncomingData (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:125:16)
2024-06-27 06:34:43     at MessageStream._write (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:33:9)
2024-06-27 06:34:43     at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)
2024-06-27 06:34:43     at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:333:10)
2024-06-27 06:34:43     at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:337:10)
2024-06-27 06:34:43     at Socket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:809:22)
2024-06-27 06:34:43     at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28) {
2024-06-27 06:34:43   ok: 0,
2024-06-27 06:34:43   code: 18,
2024-06-27 06:34:43   codeName: 'AuthenticationFailed',
2024-06-27 06:34:43   connectionGeneration: 7,
2024-06-27 06:34:43   [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(2) { 'HandshakeError', 'ResetPool' }
2024-06-27 06:34:43 }
2024-06-27 06:34:43 
2024-06-27 06:34:43 Node.js v18.20.3
2024-06-27 06:34:40 
2024-06-27 06:34:40

Everything worked fine when I didn't pass the user and password data like following:
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "${PORT}:${PORT}"
    environment:
      - PORT=${PORT}
      - CONNECTION_STRING=${CONNECTION_STRING}
      - ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET=${ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET}
    depends_on:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 8081:8081

The .env was also like:
CONNECTION_STRING=mongodb://mongo:27017/key_ring_backend_3

I don't have any issues when working this way during development.
But is it okay to create a mongo server without setting root user and password during production.
Or should I not create a mongo server in this way using docker and instead use something like the online mongodb service.

should the connection string be in quotes?

"Everything worked fine when I didn't pass the user and password" - yes but then your MongoDB works without authentication. I would not recommend that. At MongoDB Atlas (cloud service) authentication cannot be disabled.

Maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470

@ewokx can you explain a bit more clearly ?

@WernfriedDomscheit I'm still lost, what should I do.

So I found the issue.
For the mongo connection I added the volume as
volumes:
  - ./data:/data/db

When the using docker-compose and creating the containers, mongo initializes it's admin using the values provided the first time the docker-compose up command is run.
In my case I had run the docker-compose.yml file initially without setting any MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME and MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD. This caused the admin db to be empty without any users. This meant that I wouldn't even be able to run commands like db.getUsers() even in the mongosh.
Now even if I add MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME and MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD to the docker-compose.yml and run it, it won't be added to the admin db because the volume I set took only the values that was used during the first time it was initialised.
Fix:
I deleted the data directory from my local system , deleted the running containers and ran the docker-compose.yml file after setting MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME and MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD values. This fixed things.

Try this connection string:
mongodb://admin:adminpassword@mongo:27017/key_ring_backend_3?authSource=admin

I guess the user is created in admin database. Without authSource the driver tries to authenticate in key_ring_backend_3 database but that's not the database where the user is created.

Still not working, I found user not found error in mongo's logs:
"user":"admin","db":"admin","error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user "admin" for db "admin""

Check existing users with db.getUsers() - I have no clue about Docker and I don't know how it creates the users.

I got unauthorized error:
MongoServerError[Unauthorized]: not authorized on admin to execute command { usersInfo: 1, lsid: { id: UUID("2ec6e4ca-88fa-45f3-8e62-306d2e847392") }, $db: "admin" }

As said, I have no idea how docker creates the admin user. Sorry.

you need to login first in mongo to check users. get in to admin db first use admin and then type db.auth('username') and enter your password. if you are able to login then you can execute db.getUsers() . if you did login successfully then your users permissions doesnt let you execute that command. refer to this : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/built-in-roles/
